# How to make a sword swing effect

Tags: java, 2d, slick, graphic-effects

I'm working on a 2d java game on Slick engine and I always wondered how to make swing effects when striking with a sword? How to code something like this what's in the game Hollow Fear? Example from YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ES7p4RXlNzQ#t=12).

[image]

([Image source](http://megagames.com/demos/hollowfear-demo))

Answer (score 1):

You've got two simple options:

Generate particles based on the velocity of the sword in the form of [motion lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_lines)

Draw up sprites and iterate through these using frames (couple of examples at http://www.spriters-resource.com/genesis_32x_scd/shinobi3/sheet/20808/)